# Which is the best json rpc lib for jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, json-rpc

I want the implement a json rpc server in jetty.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no good one since JSON-RPC protocol is reasonable simple to implement in any language so I think you can grab a JSON library like Gson that de/serialize objects to JSON and create your JSON-RPC compliant request/response object.